# jQuery touchstart not working for blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I have here is with `touchstart`. Whats happening instead of behaving like click when you click into another focused input it adds the wanted class to footer. `Touchstart` doesn't. Instead it seem to act to quickly for the blur and the blur happens after.

Anyone know how to stop this so `touchstart` behaves like click?

```js
$('input:not(:radio)').on('click touchstart', function (e) {
  if(e.type==='click'){}else{
   $('footer').addClass('touched');
  } 
}).on('blur', function () {
   $('.touched').removeClass('touched');
});
```

```css
footer{background:blue;display:block;height:50px;}
footer.touched{background:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `focus` instead of `click touchstart`?

Comment: This is specifically for a tocuhevent

Comment: Well, you are using `blur`.  Blur and focus are handled differently on touch devices.  What are you really trying to accomplish?  You are mixing and matching blur/focus and touch events which I believe is the cause of your issue.  Each platform handles the order a little differently, and in this case I don't think `blur` fires until after the `touchstart` event on the second input.

Comment: How about using `touchleave` instead of `blur`?

Comment: @ChrisHappy not sure how you thought that was a duplicate.

Comment: @JeffB Touchend same result

Comment: @JeffB I can roughly solve it with using settimeout but IOS wont respond to anything less than 400ms so theirs quite the stutter of the effect. It also doesnt feel to safe doing it that way

Comment: @DCdaz ...[facepalm]

Comment: @DCdaz If you just use the `click` and `blur` events on iOS, it works fine.

Comment: @JeffB yes it does but then it also works on desktop :P, its to combat the keyboard showing and due to other reasons i cant rely on the normal methods but its ok I figured out  work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured out a way to get it to work and also eliminate any painful flickering of the footer animating between input focus'.

```js
$('input:not(:radio)').on('click touchstart', function (e) {
  if(e.type==='click'){}else{
   $('#form-footer').hide();
   setTimeout(function(){ $('#form-footer').addClass('touched').show(); }, 400);
  } 
}).on('blur', function () {      
   $('.touched').removeClass('touched');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similiar issues trying to get a Bootstrap 5 button to work the same between mouse clicks and using touch screens.

My required cause and affect as follows:

I'm using the same button to change a varibale from true to false, then press the same button again it reverts the var from false back to true. So in essence I'm using a single button to latch on, then press it again and it latches off.

In the code sample below, I am changing the style of the button based upon what mode it has been set to.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary ms-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="Draw Connector" id="drawConnectorModeButton" data-bs-animation="false">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-highlighter-line fa-lg"></i>
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Remove the blur from the bootsrtap buttons once released.
$(".btn").mouseup(function () {
    $(this).blur();
})

var drawConnectorModeActive = false;

$('#drawConnectorModeButton').on('click touchend', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#drawConnectorModeButton').tooltip('hide');
    if (drawConnectorModeActive == true) { // Off
        $('#drawConnectorModeButton').removeClass('btn-secondary').addClass('btn-outline-secondary');
        drawConnectorModeActive = false;
    } else { // On
        $(this).blur();
        $('#drawConnectorModeButton').removeClass('btn-outline-secondary').addClass('btn-secondary');
        drawConnectorModeActive = true;
    }
});
```